# Why my Nested Route not working properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

My `Home`, `Group`, `Learn`, `Message`, `Profile` component is not working? There are multiple `Routes` but in nested routes I want to show the navbar and the body component which is `Home`, `Group`, `Learn` etc.

[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJyVy.png)

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route index element={<Login />} />
    <Route path="Login" element={<Login />} />
    <Route path="Register" element={<Registration />} />
    <Route path="RegisterDetails" element={<PersonalDetails />} />
    <Route path="EduDetails" element={<PersonalDetails2 />} />
    <Route path="Skills" element={<Skills />} />
    <Route path="app" element={<Nav />}>
      <Route path="Home" element={<HomePage />} />
      <Route path="Group" element={<Group />} />
      <Route path="Learn" element={<Learn />} />
      <Route path="Message" element={<Message />} />
      <Route path="Profile" element={<Profile />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: If this is React Router v6, do you have an Outlet in your Nav-component?

Answer (score 1):

Nested routes work by having their parent route component render an `Outlet`.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Nav = () => {
  ...

  return (
    <>
      <nav>
        ...nav links...
      </nav>
      <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render element content here
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a slight change in react router dom v6. Now it doesn't work like that. You have to specify an outlet on the parent route and then you can specify children routes inside that wrapper. For a better understanding you can check this [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-glitter-cochny?file=/src/routes.jsx). It has all the specified routes in the same order.